# In Docusign how to access 'Request the authorization code' without open a browser

Tags: extjs, docusignapi

I am creating embedded signature REST API POC web project using **DOCUSIGN**. We are using docusign developer account. We have implemented the eSignature API  in our project.

**Note*-** For getting the **authorization code** we need to run the url in the browser everytime.
But i want to know that how we can get the **authorization code** without run into browser.
Because url is not is giving the excat response using ajax call.

For Authorization Code Grant:

**URL** - [https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id={iKey}&redirect_uri={callback}](https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=%7BiKey%7D&redirect_uri=%7Bcallback%7D)

But when we run the above url in the browser, then we can get the **authorization code**.

[image]

When we make API call with the above url ,we are not getting **authorization code**. Below code-

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id={iKey}&redirect_uri={callback}",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    noCache: true,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (response, opts) {
        console.log("Fetch auth code Success: ", response);
    },
    failure: function (response, opts) {
        console.log("Fetch auth code Failure: ",response);
    }
});
```

I want above API call to get the reponse as **authorization code**

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: The authorization code is everything after **code=**

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!***

Answer (score 0):

Video - https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=4524738590972824

Any programming lang you use can give you access to URL parameters and like Ivan said, the parameter name is `code`.

If you meant - how to find this code w/o browser, it's simple, in your own code, you find this URL parameter which was added to your own website, where you redirected the user back after login.

If you meant - how can we do this without having a browser at all (console app etc.) then you will need to use [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/).

Comment: In JWT also asking to run in the browser to get the JWT tokens. How we can get the JWT tokens without login in API call or not in browser? Give some video or link step to get JWT tokens.

Comment: Added JWT video link in the answer

Comment: In my case, User will open the web application and should get the pdf file on the same page with the esignature column. When the user will click on esignature button it should open the signature popup on the same page and user can sign and submit.
If we use JWT token, how we can get the jwt token without switching to another browser.

Comment: Not sure why you would have to switch to another browser. I don't see the issue.

Comment: How we can get the JWT token response of this url "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id={iKey}&redirect_uri={callback}" without calling in the browser url?

Comment: This is not JWT, this is auth code grant. Are you mixing the terms? or are you using Auth Code Grant?

Comment: I think i sent the wrong url, the correct url as given in documentation (https://docusign.github.io/postman-collections/) For JSON Web Token Grant is 

https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id={{iKey}&redirect_uri={callback}

Comment: Are you talking about consent? consent is only required once and doesn't have to be part of the JWT flow

Comment: Yes it is regarding the consent. In case of multiuser how we can manage the consent and send the respective API call.
Can you share any blog or link for more information.

Comment: Yes it is regarding the consent. In case of multiuser how we can manage the consent and send the respective API call.
Can you share any blog or link for more information.

Comment: you can do administrative consent for the entire organization. This way you don't need each user to consent individually. 
https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-admin-consent-external/

Comment: As we don't have admin access. What is the way to get the admin access in developer account?
I have tried this url - ( https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?
response_type=YOUR_RESPONSE_TYPE
    &scope=openid
    &client_id=YOUR_INTEGRATION_KEY
    &state=YOUR_CUSTOM_STATE
    &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
    &admin_consent_scope=YOUR_REQUESTED_SCOPES )

But I am getting message like - You are not an organization admin. Please contact your DocuSign Administrator.

What i do for this? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: you cannot do this without admin access. Find who is your admin and ask them to help

Comment: We have Integrating DocuSign with Salesforce. So i want to know that Docusign ESignature have any integration with SAP ECC system. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.docusign.com/solutions/sap has all the information

Comment: We are looking for DocuSign eSignature Accelerator for SAP ERP Central Component (ECC). Kindly share the document and video to get the detail. Thanks.

Comment: If there's no such out-of-the-box solution/integration, you would have to build one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question is confusing. There are several different patterns. Choose the one that best fits your needs:

### The app user has a DocuSign account

For example, a salesperson uses your app to send out contracts for signature. The app also enables the salesperson to counter-sign the contracts.

In this pattern, the person who is using your app has a (paid) login to DocuSign. Best: enable the user to login to DocuSign using the OAuth Authorization Code grant flow.

Note: This flow can only be used from a `confidential` OAuth client (a server, not a browser-controlled flow). See [RFC 6749 § 2.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-2.1) for more information on `confidential` vs `public` OAuth clients.

If your app, running in a browser, wants to initiate the authentication flow, then you **must** use the OAuth Implicit grant flow (browser-based software is always a public client).

### The app user does not have a DocuSign account

For example, a customer portal that enables your end customers to sign their contracts or requests.

In this case, the app developer should create a "system user" that will be used to obtain an access token that the developer will then use for eSign API calls.

A system user is a DocuSign user account such as "Finance Department." The application uses the OAuth JWT authentication flow to impersonate the Finance Department and receive an access token that represents the Finance Department "user."

Note: like the Authorization Code grant, the JWT OAuth flow can **only** be used by confidential clients. So your back-end server can implement the JWT flow, but a mobile app cannot. A browser-based app can't use the JWT flow either--you must use a back-end server.

Comment: Above secnario is not clear, My scenario is below as-

Used case
We have a web application developed using HTML5, Javascript, and CSS3 from which we want to sign a sales contract pdf from the end customer. It’s a responsive web application which can be used from desktop/laptop, tablet or mobile phones. We intend to use the e-signature REST API directly without using any SDK.


Please read the second comment for more details.

Comment: E-Signature possible in two ways:

1. Sales representative is face-to-face with the customer, shows the contract to the customer on his (sales representative’s) device and the customer signs. [Will be the most use method as it’s a high value sale]
2. Send an e-mail to customer to sign the contract. [Used in exceptional cases]

Questions/Requests

1. What is the appropriate authentication method to be used in this case?
2. Is it mandatory for the end customer, who will be signing the document to have a DocuSign account? If NO, then how does this technically work.


Thanks

Comment: @Balmukundkumar -- Since the app's user is your salesperson (who has a DocuSign account), use Authorize Code grant for authenticationof the salesperson. Use the InPerson Signer recipient type for the signer (customer) The customer does not need a docusign account. If this is not clear then please ask about your two scenarios in either a new question or two new questions. StackOverflow is not a back and forth forum system.